# To make a linq with a multiple foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have several foreach chained.
I would like to know if it is possible to do a linq synthesis of these foreach.

```
foreach(var item in parameter)
{
     foreach (var worksheets in item.Item6.Worksheets)
     {
         var worksheetName = worksheets.Value.Name;
         foreach (var dynamicRange in worksheets.Value.DynamicRanges)
         {
             var dynamicRangeRowStartIndex = dynamicRange.RowStartIndex;
             var dynamicRangeColumnStartIndex = dynamicRange.ColumnStartIndex;
             foreach (var node in dynamicRange.Nodes)
             {
                 var nodeDirection = node.Direction;
                 foreach (var rule in node.Rules)
                 {
                     reportWorkbook.Worksheets.Values.First(c => c.Name == worksheetName).DynamicRanges.First(c => c.RowStartIndex == dynamicRangeRowStartIndex && c.ColumnStartIndex == dynamicRangeColumnStartIndex)
                     .NodeByDirection(nodeDirection).Rules[ruleCount].DefinitionRule.ContextItem = item.Item6.Worksheets.Values.First(c => c.Name == worksheetName).DynamicRanges.First(c => c.RowStartIndex == dynamicRangeRowStartIndex && c.ColumnStartIndex == dynamicRangeColumnStartIndex)
                     .NodeByDirection(nodeDirection).Rules[ruleCount].DefinitionRule.ContextItem;
                     ruleCount++;                                        
                }
                ruleCount = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?
Thank you

Comment: The two outer-most foreach can easily be combined into `foreach (var worksheet in parameter.Select(x => x.item.Item6.Worksheets))`

Comment: you can easily achieve this with the help of Linq and SelectMany with where condition please use that.

Comment: Honestly don see any benefits in using linq here.

Comment: @FilipCordas Is a foreach loop like this correct for you?

Comment: @LudovicRoux There is nothing wrong with using foreach loops. They perform better and are easier to debug. There could be room to optimize you code but switching to linq will save you a few lines of code at best.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think you meant `foreach (var worksheets in parameter.Select(item => item.Item6.Worksheets))`

Comment: @FilipCordas "they perform better" better than what? LinQ is basically a collection of foreach methods

Comment: @NetMage yes, small typo

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Except LINQ involves function calls and lambda creation and execution versus `foreach` which is just linear code.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto There can be a lot of overhead with Linq especially with complex queries. In this case I think there will be a small difference if the code is written with linq. Note I am not saying don't use linq just that in this case there is noting to be gained.